Download PDF file using react js from laravel API
I'm using React js and from a laravel API. I try to download a PDF file but instead it's just open it in the same window, by clicking the button Download cv executing the function related.
Please can you help me to download the file in browser  download box. I have seen some resolutions still but have the same problem.
Here is my code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Login } from "./parts/login";
import { UseStateContext } from "../context/ContextProvider";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import FormToAddFile from "./parts/BioParts/formToAddFile";
import AlertNotification from "./parts/AlertNotification";
import axiosClient from "../axios-client";
import DownloadPDF from "./parts/BioParts/DownloadPdf";

export default function Bio(){
   const {token,user,showLogin,setShowLogin}=UseStateContext();
   const [showFormToAddFile,setShowFormToAddFile]=useState(false); //state to manage showing form to add CV file
   const [file,setFile]=useState("");
const handleShowLogin=()=>{
   if(showLogin){
      setShowLogin(false)
   }else{
      setShowLogin(true)
   }
}

// function for showing form to add a CV file 
const handleShowToAddFile=()=>{
   if(showFormToAddFile){
      
      setShowFormToAddFile(false)
   }else{
      setShowFormToAddFile(true)
   }
}
// 

const ShowHideFormAddFile=(value)=>{     //callback to hide and show form file adding 
console.log("showhideform",value)
setShowFormToAddFile(value)
}

const handleDownloadCv=()=>{
  
   axiosClient.get(`/getfiles/${1}`,{
      headers:{
         'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',

      }
   }).then(({data})=>{
      console.log(data.file.image)
      if(data.file.image){
         setFile(data.file.image)

      }
   }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
   })
}
useEffect(()=>{
   handleDownloadCv()
},[])

const downloadFileAtURL=(url)=>{
   const fileName = url.split("/").pop();
   const aTag=document.createElement("a");
   aTag.href=url;
   aTag.setAttribute("download",fileName);
   document.body.appendChild(aTag);

   aTag.click();
   aTag.remove();
}

    return(
      <div className="Bio grid  lg:grid-cols-2 lg:gap-6  -z-20 grid-cols-1 ">
           {      console.log(file)
           }
            <div className="left max-sm:grid max-sm:justify-center">
               
              

               {
               token? <div> <div className="flex">
                  <button onClick={()=>{downloadFileAtURL("http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/"+file)}}  formTarget="_blank" className="flex items-center"   id="downloadCv" >Download Cv</button>
                  <button className="ml-2">See profile</button>
                  <button className="ml-2 imgIconEdit0">
                  <label htmlFor="iconinput">
                  <img onClick={handleShowToAddFile}  className="" src="/icon/crayon.png" alt="" />
                  </label>
                  </button>
               

                  </div>
                  </div>
                  :
                  <>
                  <button onClick={handleShowLogin} className="md:mx-auto">Connect Now</button>

                  </> 
                  
               }
               
            </div>
            <div className="right">
               {showFormToAddFile && <FormToAddFile ShowHideFormAddFile={ShowHideFormAddFile}/> }
            </div>

      </div> 
    )
}

I have tried many times but gives me the same result.
